# create delay before the next click on doorbell

Tags: transistors, power

I'm in a place where noisy people have the habit to click the doorbell many times ding ding ding, is there a way to make the doorbell, that when he clicks it, then he should wait 20 seconds for example until the next click? (cut the current for 20 seconds )  Sorry for that abstract question, but I have little experience with electricity, the current is 230 - 240 Volt.

Comment: Yes, this is doable but, given you have little experience with electricity and think that current is measured in volts AND the fact that the voltage is lethal, I'd just find someone else to do it.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but can you guide me , what components should i buy , and will ask a friend to do the circut

Comment: That's not how this site works; it's a question and answer site and the breadth of each question is limited. Plus how much time would I have to give you to get this working with very little benefit other than you being less annoyed with your doorbell.

Comment: look for a time-relay which operates in the range of a doorbell. I need to look, but if I remember right here in germany 9-18V are common for doorbells. The timerelay - correctly connected will allow you to add that retrigger delay. Maybe you need another relay or so... so research, draw a nice schematic and come back with some good questions about it...

Comment: If you can replace the bell and get the signal safely from its likely moderate-voltage AC origins into the context of low voltage DC electronics (perhaps with an optocoupler or relay?) then this kind of lock out is trivial; if you cannot, it is not.

Comment: It should be noted that most 240v doorbells actually have a transformer somewhere (up in the roof), so the pushbutton out the front actually only switches 12vAC and the bell is only 12vAC . As others have suggested using a timer relay would be your simplest option, it would have to operate on the 12vAC.  Omron have a large range of timer relays. http://www.omron.com.au/products/category/control-components/timers/analog-timers/index.html

Comment: Any easy and viable Do It Yourself solution would start by migrating from 240 AC to low voltage DC (12V DC for example). 12V AC can be difficult to control even if it's less dangerous. IMO such system already exists for 240V AC. Ask a professional electric store. These things are not cheap but the easiest way.

Comment: @Fredled  As far as I am aware, all doorbells operate off low voltage, either battery (rare nowadays except for some new wireless models) or AC , the striker generally uses an AC solenoid, as AC allows for a larger movement of the solenoid plunger., typically the transformer is 16vAC , allowing for 12v AC at the solenoid with long wires. The doorbell switch is too small, and being exposed to the elements, and requires a small light bulb, none of that is possible while complying with 240vAC standards. Also the wire has to be run through architraves/bricks without conduit.

Comment: @BobT I have a bought an installed a 240V AC doorbell and installed myself at a time I knew nothing about electricity and electronics, 20 years ago. The 240V hot wire runs to two knobs, one being near the yard gate. The low voltage stuff is inside the bell box. No external supply. So IMO, it depends where you live.

Answer (score 2):

*** Important Note: this answer is not an endorsement for a particular manufacturer or distributor, you should use a search engine of your choice to look for "100mA PTC" , download datasheets, and make your own informed choices ***

Assuming you have a standard doorbell , that operates off a bell transformer (up in the roof) with 12VAC fed to the switch , and a solenoid type ringer that has two metal chimes (ding when pressed, dong when released) , then the simplest option would be to install a PTC (positive temperature coefficient) thermistor or poly-fuse ,  these are normally designed to protect low voltage circuits instead of fuses, as they will reset once the fault clears. The thermistor heats up when excessive current passes, and the resistance increase dramatically. PTC's are commonly sold in electronic hobby shops as "speaker protectors" , they are usually yellow discs about 10mm diameter.  [image]

In your case, I'd guess your coil is about 1amp at 12v, so I would be looking at possibly a 100mA PTC  to get a 1second delay see here https://au.mouser.com/Circuit-Protection/Thermistors/Resettable-Fuses-PPTC/_/N-axfyt?P=1z0z7l5&Keyword=PTC+100mA&FS=True  . the first part in that search has a datasheet , https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/643/ds-CP-0ZRR-series-1664153.pdf , please read this datasheet, from this we get a time delay graph : [image: PTC delay] , I have highlighted in red the region of interest , a 100mA PTC is curve B,  if you look along the X axis to 1amp (your bell current) and then go up to curve B , it meets at about 0.5sec, so the bell coil will release in about 0.5sec.

In order to get the optimum time delay, I'd suggest buying about 4 of the 50mA PTC's and wire up as many as needed in parallel to get the required delay. The PTC's go in series with the pushbutton, and are quite small, so will fit inside the button assembly, simply remove the pushbutton cover, disconnect one wire, and connect the PTC between that wire and the screw terminal, use a wire nut to join the other PTC lead to the wire.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyqcKL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

First device that comes to mind is a [Pneumatic Time Delay Switch.](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/152445636760) It’s a bit pricey but definitely could do the trick.

With this one you can adjust the length of time people can press it again from 30 seconds to 20 minutes. Hope this helps!

Comment: No, that's not going to work.  Beside the fact that it is a response only to the *prohibted* "shopping" aspect of the question, the device which you suggest purchasing does not function to *lock out* the circuit as needed, rather it will maintain the circuit *held on* for a period of time after the button push.  Rather than decreasing the annoyance, that would compound it!

Comment: OP is looking for a component based solution, not comparing two products or figuring out which brand it better. Also, I feel like if OPs people at the door feel the need to press the bell multiple times, it is based on a system that sees a press and runs a fixed length tone, thus holding it down doesn’t increase the tone time hence the need for multiple presses - could definitely be wrong though, just my thinking.

Comment: A "component based solution" by which you really mean one consisting of "products one can purchase" is *explicitly off topic* here.  Even if it works...

Comment: @ChrisStratton, why exactly are component based solutions off-topic? It's difficult to imagine any electronic engineering solution to any real world problem that has a solution using zero components.  I can see possible issues in recommending a specific vendors product as this would be "advertising"  Unfortunately datasheets don't exist for generic components, so how do we point out to newbies datasheets that they could learn from..

Comment: @Bobt the question is asking for a product to buy, hence it is off topic.  You may have found a clever solution, but the quest here really wasn't for a circuit element.